# Flask OIDC is not detecting the access token when it is sent using a cookie, but it functions as expected when sent through the authorization header

Tags: keycloak, cookie-httponly, flask-oidc

Cookie is sent using ajax by setting withCredentials: true

Getting the below error:

{
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "Token required but invalid"
}

How to set in flask oidc that it should look for access_token present in cookies?

Comment: You need to ensure that your Flask application is correctly receiving or validating the access token sent from the client. Are you using Flask-OIDC library? If the library is configured correctly and the token is passed properly, it should validate the token.

Comment: Yes, I am using Flask-OIDC. I can see the token also in the cookie headers

I think it is looking only in Authorization headers instead of looking inside cookies

Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Linux"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=%22cce63416-19fa-4e11-b1ce-_ga_TDV72PN77Y=GS1.1.1701961460.2.1.1701961594.0.0.0;access_token_cookie=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJqdUFvU19HOGxB